# Which is the preferred MVVM framework for Xamarin development?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Which is the preferred MVVM framework for Xamarin cross platform development? Any suggestions from experience will be helpful.

thanks!

Comment: Are you developing a Xamarin.Forms app, or a traditional Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android app?

Comment: Classic Xamarin . Not forms

Comment: see this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter18/

Comment: Here's comparison of MVVM Frameworks I put together to help you decide:  https://github.com/rogerwcpt/xamarin-mvvvm-frameworks.

Comment: Why does Stack Overflow play god and close this because it thinks the answers are  opinion based?   Aren't opinions of other developers worth anything?  Its a perfectly valid question that developers should be able to answer without being blocked by the Stackoverflow lords.

Answer (score 20):

## Traditional Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android

There are many MVVM Frameworks available for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android development: [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross), [MvvmLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net), [PrismMVVM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Mvvm), [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net).

I've had the most success using [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net) for MVVM and [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat) for IoC.

The best feature about [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net) is that it doesn't require any ViewModel Navigation. You may think that ViewModel-based Navigation is a good thing, but it can make your life much more difficult when implementing complex navigation patterns. iOS and Android have view-based navigation built-in, and I recommend leveraging those instead of trying to re-create the wheel by using ViewModel-based navigation.

## Xamarin.Forms

*You mentioned in the comments that you're not using Xamarin.Forms, but I wanted to include this in case another developer has a similar question for Xamarin.Forms.*

Don't use an MVVM Framework with Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Forms has a binding engine included. I've seen many developers over-complicate their Xamarin.Forms projects by implementing heavy frameworks like MVVMCross into Xamarin.Forms without receiving much benefit.

Xamarin.Forms doesn't include an IoC container, and you may want to add one to your project: [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC), [Autofac](https://autofac.org), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org), [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat).

I have had the most success using [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat).

Comment: Are you still recommend to not use mvvm framework?

Comment: Prism is only for Xamarin forms.

Comment: As of its current state today - I strongly do not recommend using ReactiveUI. Unless you have an experienced developer with strong background from general MVVM and reactive patterns. ReactiveUI is a powerful tool. But its documentation and support is very weak: juniors and middles constantly run into problems what makes development insufficient and turns your seniors into a help desk for app devs.